# Serana just stays in attack mode

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I have already looked up multiple things on how to fix this glitch, but found no answer.
I may not have been reading anything right, but it is really ticking me off. I just need a direct solution.

I am in the quest "Chasing Echoes", she's been following me throughout the mission until we hit the big looking lunchroom full of skeletons, and she just stays there. I went to go, brought the gargoyle back and she gets farther as you make it known you're in an attack.

Though she just stays in attack mode, either still casting a spell or just crouching there in that same spot.

How can I fix this?

I'm playing on the PC.

Answer (score 6):

This happened to me, if you mean the Graveyard. Just attack her until she goes into bleedout (when she's out of health and on one knee). She should be fixed when she gets back up.

Comment: For those of us on consoles, this solution is a good alternative to using console commands.

Answer (score 2):

Hm. First of all, Fus-Roh-Dah is the solution to most of NPC problems, just shout her through the rooms once and it should work. If it doesn't, open the console, click on her and type

```
setav aggression 0
```

This is resetting the aggression value and she should behave as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Cast a calming spell on her. Harmony will work for sure. This just happened to me.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar bug happen recently. The console command `StopCombatAlarmOnActor` worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

if she does not reset on bleedout, try realoading the game, or do the harmony shout, then use the 'setav aggression 0' command, all together. if THAT doesnt work, id suggest trying to talk to her?

Comment: That's a nice combination of the existing answers, but doesn't add anything new (trying to talk to her is impossible when she's in attack mode). Please refrain from posting answers that don't compliment existing answers.